# How to use Interface in brightscript for functions

Tags: roku, brightscript

I want a function need to be called using interface-implementation model.  I have read that roku has provision to have a function inside the interface portion in brightscript's document.
So I tried but failed. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Please add code you tried to launch.

Comment: Yes, this question needs more detail to be answerable. Suggest showing examples (in code) of what was tried.

Comment: In my case, there is a component in a.xml and it's script in a.brs. In script  I have a method foo() in both the interface and implementation segments. Now I add a.brs in component b and trying to access foo() method and I got error

Comment: @ganka ok, but can you post that actual code & error in your question (edit the question)? otherwise this question is not answerable.

Comment: U.Mitic hit the nail on the head. The params that are passed when you call your function are supposed to be wrapped inside of an associative array or an array. Here is more information on that. It makes the whole process rather tedious so I don't usually use these. https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Handling+Application+Events#HandlingApplicationEvents-FunctionalFields

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you would implement a function inside an interface:

For example, create a custom screen named "audioPlayer" and in the audioPlayer.xml file add:

```
<interface>
    <function name="doSomething" />
</interface>
```

In the audioPlayer.brs file declare "doSomething" function:

```
Function doSomething(param as String)
    print param
End Function
```

Now in your HomeScene.xml add this custom created "audioPlayer" screen/component and in HomeScene.brs init() function add:

```
m.audioPlayer = m.top.findNode("audioPlayer")
```

You can call your doSomething() function from HomeSceene.brs  with this peace of code:

```
param = "Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?"
m.audioPlayer.callFunc("doSomething",param)
```

Comment: Nice, simple and answered with a clear working example.

Comment: @U.mitic hello Sorry But  I read your answer and your blog also But I face some issue on here `Interface not a member of BrightScript Component (runtime error &hf3) in pkg:/components/ChannelList.brs(19)
019:   m.WisePanel.callFunc("doSomething",param)`

Comment: my another try to same issue here `Interface not a member of BrightScript Component (runtime error &hf3) in pkg:/components/PanelSet.brs(12)
012:     m.KeyboardDialogExample.callFunc("doSomething",param)` to use different two file.

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya - To me it looks like You did not add "doSomething" function to the m.WisePanel interface in .xml file of m.WisePanel.

Comment: Here I use two components one is wisepanel and another is keyboarddialog. Wisepanel dedicates to first screen and keyboarddialog dedicate second screen. So I interface tag write in second screen it keyboarddialog and write function on brs file. And dosomthing call in wisepanel. Is it correct?

Comment: In my case, I am not being able to access the component by findNode function. It prints out as an invalid.

Comment: You probably did not append it to the parent node. findNode function will not work if the node you are trying to find is not a child to some node.

Comment: This worked like a charm for me to manage focus easily. thanks!